# WHMCS how can I conditionally hide the primary navigation bar on the top of the client pages?

Tags: whmcs

I am developing a web site  selling web hosting and domain registration so I am using WHMCS but I am facing a problem I want to make a custom page under WHMCS directory to allow the admin user to change product's details without showing the top navigation bar which created by WHMCS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure by Admin user, but if you mean you want to remove the primary menu from client area, add this code to a php file inside: whmcs_dir/includes/hooks (say nomenu.php)

```
add_hook('ClientAreaNavbars', 1, function ()
{
    // Get the current navigation bars.
    $primaryNavbar = Menu::primaryNavbar();
    $secondaryNavbar = Menu::secondaryNavbar();
    $children = $primaryNavbar->getChildren();
    if (!is_null($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $primaryNavbar->removeChild($child);
        }
    }

    $children = $secondaryNavbar->getChildren();
    if (!is_null($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $secondaryNavbar->removeChild($child);
        }
    }

});
```

Also, add css code to hide the menubar remaining after removing the items:

`#main-menu {display: none}`

***One note though***: even if you hide the menu items, if logged in user knows the page link, which is not secret, he can type the URL directly in the address bar to visit it.

For example, to access my domains page in whmcs: http://whmcs-url.com/clientarea.php?action=domains

Your option to have better control is to check the [API functions](https://developers.whmcs.com/api/).